# handling .net web applications with CI /CD using TFS 2018 (TFVC)

Tags: web-applications, tfs

I need some information on handling .net web applications with CI /CD using TFS 2018 (TFVC).I am using .NET core build template, my doubts are:
1) do we need to pass MS Build Parameter to trigger Web Deploy? 
2) do we need to create a release pipeline in release definition and use some tool available to deploy web app and configure IIS settings?

Please let me know a method, i am confused.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass other parameters. The default parameters should be :

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site"
```

Yes, you need to create a release pipeline to deploy the web app using the **IIS Website Deployment** task, if no such a task, then you can install the extension [IIS Web App Deployment Using WinRM](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscs-rm.iiswebapp) and use `WinRM - IIS Web App Deployment` task to do that.

Please see below articles for details.

- [Deploy your ASP.NET Core app to a Windows virtual machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/cd/azure/aspnet-core-to-windows-vm?view=vsts&tabs=vsts)
- [Deploy your Web Deploy package to IIS servers using WinRM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-winrm?view=vsts)
- [Deploy to a Windows Virtual Machine](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/apps/cd/deploy-webdeploy-iis-deploygroups?view=vsts)
- [Building an ASP.NET Core Web App in Visual Studio Team Services
  (VSTS)](https://alastairchristian.com/building-an-asp-net-core-web-app-in-visual-studio-team-services-vsts-def820521648)

Comment: Hi Andy, i have a doubt. When creating my build definiton , what template do i need to select for .net web applications. At present i selected ASP .Net core template but i need to build my .sln file but this template points to .csproj only. So please clarify me on this..

Comment: @Mani If your ASP.NET Core web application targeting the **full .NET Framework** then you can use `ASP.NET Core (.NET Framework)` template. by default it links the solution (`*.sln`)  If  the ASP.NET Core web application targeting *.NET Core* then you can use `ASP.NET Core` template, by default it links projects (`*.csproj`).

Comment: I have few questions 1) the above MS build parameters will only build the application, am i right 2) Then to deploy it we need to create the release pipeline.I have a doubt here if i am correct then whey are we passing DeployIISpath parameter during build.. 3) To set CI build first , is it enough to pass only that MSBuild parameters.. please let me know on the above queries... thanks

Comment: @Mani For 1 and 2, Yes, you are right, based on my test, the  `DeployIISpath` parameters is not necessary if you using `IIS Website Deployment` task to deploy the application as yo can set the parameters directly within the task... 3) it's enough ,it's just for building and generate the needed files...