# .net web application build (CI /CD) using TFS 2018

Tags: tfs, web-deployment

I am setting up CI/CD setup using TFS 2018 for ASP .net web application using ASP .Net build template and source control is (TFVC), I have few questions
1) If i use

```
(/p:DeployOnBuild=true 
    /p:WebPublishMethod=Package 
    /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true 
    /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true 
    /p:DesktopBuildPackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\WebApp.zip" 
    /p:DeployIisAppPath="Default Web Site")
```

MS build parameters will only build the application, am i right ?

2) Then to deploy it we need to create a release pipeline.I have a doubt here if i am correct then whey are we passing DeployIISpath parameter as a argument during build..
3) To set CI build first , is it enough to pass only that MSBuild parameters?

please let me know on the above queries...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [handling .net web applications with CI /CD using TFS 2018 (TFVC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52115596/handling-net-web-applications-with-ci-cd-using-tfs-2018-tfvc)